# How to rename file without timestamp at the end of it

Tags: linux, rename

I want to rename the bunch of files like from following to

```
TEST_API_CICD_03Sep2019_09:12:19.json
TEST_API_CICD_03Sep2019_09:12:20.json
```

to this

```
TEST_API_CICD.json
TEST_API_CICD.json
```

The file names length is not constant

Comment: Did you have a try with `rename`? See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Is the format of the timestamp always the same? If the length of the file name is not constant, how do the file names differ? In your example you would rename both files to the same name, so at the end you will only have one file with the contents of the file you renamed last. Is this what you expect?

Comment: @Philippos don't say `rename` unless you for certain whether you're getting `prename` or `rename.ul` because the two are quite different.

Comment: In this example, after the rename, you will have two same file names. Is there any pattern that will be followed or the files are going to be placed in different directories?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this using a powerful Perl's regular-expression `prename` program, installed with Perl 5.<sup>1</sup>

**Run this command in the directory containing your files:**

```
prename -v 's/_\d\d[A-Za-z]+\d\d\d\d_\d\d:\d\d:\d\d((\.[^.]*)?)$/$1/g' *
```

You may change `*` *at the end of command* to the list of files you would like to rename (in case you would like to rename only some of them).

#### Translation

Rename all files in current directory by: removing "*underscore- followed by 2 digits- followed by one or more English alphabets- followed by 4 digits- followed by underscore- followed by 2 digits- followed by colon- followed by 2 digits- followed by colon- followed by 2 digits-*" THAT IS positioned just before the file extension (or the end of file name if it doesn't have extension).

#### Notes

- You can change the `-v` parameter to `-n` if you would like to see how things are going to be renamed first (without actually renaming them).
- **Your examples, if reside in the same directory, would resulted in clashed filename.** (See below)
- If newly renamed file name clashes with other existing file, or earlier renamed file name in the process; `prename` will print a warning, and the file in question will be left unrenamed. (Other later files unaffected by this problem would still continue to be renamed)
- Please be aware that there's no command to remove generic "date" at the end of filenames; there are too many date and separator formats to account for; applying wrong date format in renaming will also result in a mess. The command I gave only applies to the filename-date separator, date format, and date-extension separator seen in your examples. See *Translation* above for exact details.
- I tested this on Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 "Wheezy" i386 (with Perl 5.14.2)

P.S. Obligatory comic strip: ["Perl to the rescue!" (a.k.a XKCD #208 "*Regular Expressions*")](https://www.xkcd.com/208/)

---

<sup>1</sup> On some systems like mine, it is also the program that run when you invoke `rename`. Not same as the one from util-linux mentioned in @Philippos' comment, though. Running `man rename` and scroll down to the bottom, will tell if it was from Perl or from util-linux.

Comment: +1 for spelling out the difference, I also have this one as `rename` and that one as `rename.ul`

Answer (score -1):

I would use a combination of `ls`/`find`, `sed`, and `sh`.

```
ls |sed -E '/TEST_API_CICD/{s!^(.*TEST_API_CICD)_........._..:..:..(\.json)$!mv -i "&" "\1\2"!;p};d'
```

The first part, between `/`s, is a pattern to select which files to rename. The parts within parentheses are the parts to keep, tucked together as the new filename with `\1\2\3...`. The pattern *not* in parentheses is the part to remove. `.` (dot) is any character (like `?` in glob expressions). `.` is zero or more of any character (like  in glob expressions). `^` and `$` anchors the pattern at the start and end, so that all characters are matched.

Inspect the result (with `|more` or `|less`, or even `|grep ...` to look for oddities), and if it looks fine, run it with `|sh`.